# ng-show alters min-height in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a div that has a class of `wrapper`. Inside it has a parent div with a class of `content-wrapper`. The `wrapper` div has an `ng-show` that returns `true/false`.

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-show="firebaseUser">
   <% include ../partials/nav.ejs %>
   <div class="content-wrapper">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
   </div>
   <% include ../partials/footer.ejs %>
</div>
```

The `content-wrapper` has just a little bit of css that makes it fit the entire screen. Just in case it helps I've included the parent styles as well.

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-wrapper, .right-side {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #ecf0f5;
    z-index: 800;
}
```

Now, when I use the `ng-show` the screen scrolls farther than the height of the window.

If I inspect (and then refresh the page) it `(.content-wrapper)` looks like on page load it's given a style of `min-height: 532px;`.

If I inspect the page with no page refresh. Meaning it readjusts to the new window height it's given a style of `min-height: 422px;`.

If I don't use the `ng-show` the screen always fits the window and I have no problems.

What is `ng-show` adjusting and how do I fix this issue?

P.S. I've tried using `ng-if` instead and the result of that is the entire screen is very short and small. So, worse than `ng-show`.

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery? You've tagged it but not mentioned it in your question?

Comment: I have removed the tag. Thank you for the notice of mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not the way to work with angular. Strongly suggest reading [Thinking in angular when I have a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: This is a theme I'm trying to implement. Maybe show an example of the "correct" way to do so. I've thought about changing the includes into directives. But not sure how that would change the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure fully if angular's to blame here.

Looking at your css the parent needs to have a height of 100% for the child to have the full height of the parent.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-wrapper, .right-side {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #ecf0f5;
    z-index: 800;
}
```

[or have an in-depth read of this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Comment: @MitchEvans try and actually set values like on wrapper set a hight of 400px and on content-wrapper set height 100%. And just see if that works

Comment: That does remove the scroll.

Comment: I just don't understand why it doesn't do it when i'm not using ng-show

Comment: @MitchEvans its because the child needs to know what the parents height is. Look read the link in my answer, that will help you setup the css correctly.

Comment: I see nothing talking about Height. Just width.

Comment: Re-reading your answer, I'm not sure you understand my problem. The divs are going pas the height of my window so I'm having to scroll. Your answer makes it sound like you're trying to make it taller.